# ASP.net Identity - How does UserManager<TUser> Have Access To Roles?

Tags: asp.net-identity, user-management, account-management

... and we're only inside Microsoft.AspNet.Identity. (We're not even looking at the base implementation at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.)

The `UserManager` class only takes in an `IUserStore<TUser>` at constructor. It does not have an `IUserRoleStore<TUserRole>` which I imagine would need to be accessed to determine whether `UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(string, string)` or not.

I'm thinking UserStore's implementation would have an `IsInRoleAsync(string, string)` function as well (then it would all make sense), but it does not.

Another strange thing - how can UserManager be able to perform password setting and resetting if all it knows inside its implementation is that we're dealing with an `IUser` - with only `string Id` and `string UserName` as properties?

Answer (score 6):

Alright, after much digging and lucky discovery - it turns out that Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core comes with a few other interfaces, in particular, `IUserRoleStore<TUser>` and `IUserPasswordStore<TUser>` **which both "inherit"(implement) IUserStore<TUser>**.

So if we wanted role management capabilities, we implement `IUserRoleStore<TUser>`:

```
class MyUser : IUser
{
        // Additional properties and functions not shown for brevity.
}

class MyUserStore : IUserRoleStore<MyUser>
{
    public bool IsInRole(string username, string role)
    {
       // Implementation not show for brevity.
    }


    /* We would then implement the rest of the required functions.

       We would have a data context here that has access to users,
       user-roles, and roles.
    */
}
```

Now we can pass `MyUserStore` to `UserManager<TUser>`, because `MyUserStore` is an `IUserRoleStore<TUser>`, which is an `IUserStore<TUser>`:

```
UserManager<MyUser> UM = new UserManager<MyUser>(new MyUserStore());
```

I suspect, then, that the source code for `UserManager<TUser>` uses reflection to find out whether the store passed into it at constructor implements one of `IUserStore<TUserStore>`'s "child interfaces", in order to be able to perform role checks (if it implements `IUserRoleStore<TUser>`) or password set/reset (if it implements `IUserPasswordStore<TUser>`).

I hope you find this useful because most documentation (MVC tutorials and such) don't tell us this detail. They tell us to use the `UserStore<TUser>` implementation of Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework - where all we have to do is pass in a custom `User` object (that implements `IUser`) and we're good to go.

Comment: That's excatly how it works. You can find the source code at https://github.com/aspnet/Identity. Their doing `var cast = Store as IUserRoleStore<TUser>;` to check if your passed store implements `IUserRoleStore<TUser>`.